# Pulseaudio module-combine-sink always throws Failure

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio, bluez

I am new to pulseaudio. As per my requirement, I need my audio output to be routed to either connected speaker, bluetooth speaker, or both.
I am able to play the media file on speaker, or bluetooth headset individually, however I am not able to play on both.
I tried combining the two sinks, however it always throws me the error:
Failure: Module initialization failed
Here's is the code snippet:

```
root@raspberrypi3:~# pactl list short sinks
1       palerts module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
2       pfeedback       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
3       pringtones      module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
4       pmedia  module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
5       pdefaultapp     module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
6       peffects        module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
7       pvoicerecognition       module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
8       ptts    module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
9       pndk    module-null-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
11      alsa_output.0.analog-stereo     module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
13      bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_F3_07_6F    module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
```

For music playback:

```
root@raspberrypi3:~# paplay abc.wav -d alsa_output.0.analog-stereo  
root@raspberrypi3:~# paplay abc.wav -d bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_F3_07_6F
```

Both work as per expectation.

However the problem is with the following statement:

```
root@raspberrypi3:~# pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink-name=combine sink_properties=device.description=Combined slaves=alsa_output
.0.analog-stereo,bluez_sink.FC_58_FA_F3_07_6F
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

I tried cleaning ~/.pulse directory, Commenting module-suspend-on-idle, but nothing seems to be of any help.
Any pointers will be of great help.

Thanks for you're time.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the reason why it was not working.
On checking the logs of pulseaudio, I found that it was not able to find the module-combine-sink library.
I copied the libraries manually in /usr/lib/pulse-9.0/modules, restarted the pulseaudio, and it started working as expected, i.e. audio routed to both devices.